# Postfix PolicyD v2 (cluebringer) after checking virtual mail users

Tags: email, postfix-mta, policy, rate-limiting

I installed and integrated policyd v2 (cluebringer) into my postfix installation. I use it for ratelimit sasl authenticated email senders (quota module) and greylisting not authenticated incoming mails.

The problem is, that I have to put the policy server in front of the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` like that:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031,
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    reject_unauth_pipelining,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_unlisted_recipient
```

With this configuration the greylisting tracking of cluebringer gets filled with triples of recipients which does not have a corresponding virtual mailbox entry. The mails for these recipients could be rejected before the policy server checks greylisting and/or other things via cluebringer.

Setting `reject_unauth_destination` to the top will also reject sasl authenticated users. Setting also `permit_sasl_authenticated` to the top, then `reject_unauth_destination` and on third position `check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031` it would resolve the greylisting problem, but then it is not possible to set a quota and/or accounting limit for sasl authenticated users in cluebringer.

Is there a way to optimize this configuation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could run a seperate greylisting policy server for incoming emails at port 25 and reject invalid emails plus greylisting, and run the cluebringer policy server for incoming emails at submission port 587, assuming your users use port 587 to submit emails and not  via port 25.